# If $G$ is a graph with $2k+1$ vertices and $|E(G)| \gt k\Delta(G)$ , then $ \chi'(G) \ge \Delta(G)+1$

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

We define :
$\chi'(G)$ is the minimum number of colors we need in order to color all edges of the graph $G$.

Assume that we have a graph like $G$ with $2k+1$ vertices and  $|E(G)| \gt k\Delta(G)$.
Prove that $\chi'(G) \ge \Delta(G)+1$.

Note : By coloring, here I mean a proper coloring. So, no two adjacent edges have the same color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $\chi'(G) \geq \Delta(G)$ be definition. So it is sufficient to prove the case that $\chi'(G) = \Delta(G)$ is impossible. I prove by contradiction below.

**Proof:** Assume $\chi'(G) = \Delta(G)$. We then have
$$
|E(G)| > k \cdot \chi'(G)
$$
By Pigeonhole principle, there exists a color $c$ such that at least $k + 1$ edges of $G$ are of color $c$. However, because two edges with same color can not have common end points, there are at most $\lfloor \frac{2k + 1}{2} \rfloor = k$ edges with same color. A contradiction. Q.E.D.